# how to set select box value by id in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have 3 select box. No 1 is for division, No 2 is for district and No 3 is for city. Now when I load them on ajax call using remoteFunction it works fine. But When I want to update a value I want that for a entry the division,district and city will be selected in selecbox so that the user can change it if necessary. It works well but then district select box loads all district without following the divisionId and city loads all cities without following the districtId. I have no idea how to do it. Is there any way to load district by the divisionId !? Can anyone please help me on this please. Here are my domain and view below >>>

here ary my domain with division, district and city >>>

```
    class Committee {
    Long id
    Division division
    District district
    City city
    String committeeName
}
```

here is my update action from where i am passing value to view >>>

```
def updateCommittee(){
    Committee committee = Committee.get(Long.parseLong(params.committeeId))
    [committee: committee]
}
```

here is my view where I am setting value in select box >>>

division select box :

```
<g:select class="form-control"
      name="divisionId"
      id="divisionId"
      from="${committee.division?.list()}"
      value="${committee.division?.id}"
      optionKey="id"
      optionValue="name"
      width="130"
      required=""
      onchange="loadDistrict(this.value)"/>
```

district select box :

```
<g:select class="form-control"
      name="districtId"
      id="districtId"
      from="${committee.district?.list()}"
      value="${committee.district?.id}"
      optionKey="id"
      optionValue="name"
      width="130"
      onchange="loadCities(this.value)"
      required=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Just a little bit of change in the district select box with attribute from. Here it is below >>>

```
<g:select class="form-control"
      name="districtId"
      id="districtId"
      from="${District.findAllByDivision(committee.division)}"
      value="${committee.district?.id}"
      optionKey="id"
      optionValue="name"
      width="130"
      onchange="loadUpazila(this.value)"
      required=""/>
```